# Basic Reed-Solomon Error Correction Question

Tags: algorithm, error-handling, error-correction, reed-solomon

Does Reed-Solomon error correction work in an instance where there is a dropped byte (or multiple dropped bytes)?  For example, let's say it's a (12,8) Reed Solomon code, so theoretically it should be able to correct 2 errors (or 4 erasures if the position is known).  But, what happens if only 11 (or 10) bytes are received and one doesn't know which byte(s) were dropped?  Will Reed-Solomon error correction work?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RS decoding for erasures requires the position of the symbols "dropped" or lost. The kind of error you're talking about is due to phase distortion.

Comment: Does RS know that it is "undecidable", and if so, would it work to attempt to put a 0 or 0xFF in each possibly missing byte position and rerun until it comes back as "decidable"?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by simply cycling through the possible positions where the character might be missing and letting it try to correct your result, so let's say you received 10 characters:

```
1234567890
```

Have it correct the following values:

```
??1234567890
?1?234567890
?12?34567890
 :
1??234567890
1?2?34567890
 :
1234567890??
```

Each attempt will probably give you some result, most of which are not the one you want. But I would expect that there should be exactly one result with the minimal number of additional modifications, and that should be the one you want to use as the most likely to be correct answer.

For example, if you correct the first three numbers of the example above, you might get the following result:

```
    v
361274567890
917234567890
312734569897
 :      ^  ^
```

For the first and third case, you have additional corrections made beyond filling in the two blanks (marked with v and ^), whereas in the second case you have only the missing positions filled in and the other characters match the uncorrected input. Therefore, I would choose answer 2 as the most likely to be correct one.

Clearly, the chances that this works depend on whether there are other errors. Unfortunately I'm not able to give you a rigorous set of conditions under which this method will work for sure.

.

Another thing you can do if your message is long enough is to use an interleaving technique to basically have multiple orthogonal RS codes cover your data. That way, if one fails, you might be able to recover with another one. This method is for example used on compact discs (CDs), where it is called [CIRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-interleaved_Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_coding).

Answer (score 0):

No, Reed-Solomon can't automatically correct instances where there are missing bits, because just like most other FEC algorithms, [it was only designed to correct bit-flips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction#Types_of_FEC). If you know the position of the missing bits, you can pad your received signal at those positions so that RS can then work normally.

However, if you don't know the position, you will need to use another algorithm that supports [bit-insertion or bit-deletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction#Types_of_FEC) such as Marker Codes and Watermark Codes.

Also note that RS can be not only used for erasures but also to [process noisy bits using Forney syndrome](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_codes_for_coders#Error_and_erasure_correction).