# Reed-Solomon: encoding and decoding string has different length, any workaround for this?

Tags: python, error-correction, reed-solomon, forwarderrorcorrection

I'm trying to transfer data between two processes. Problem is while transmitting the data, sometimes the receiver received more and sometimes fewer bits than the actual sending bits. Is there any workaround for this? or Is there any mechanism to which can handle adding or deletion bits from a bit string?

As there is a chance that multiple bits might flip while transmitting, I use the Reed-Solomon library, [reedsolo](https://pypi.org/project/reedsolo/) for encoding the data before sending it. As my sending bit string and receiving bit string length doesn't match reed-Solomon throw error while I try to decode.

For example,
I'm sending 143 bit as: 
110100001101001001001110111011001010101011100010111110111000000101010101000011000111111110**11010**

and I'm receiving 142 bit as: 
110100001101001001001110111011001010101011100010111110111000000101010101000011000111111110**1101**

and I'm receiving an error message as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File 

"/home/user/Downloads/experiment/reedsololib/decode.py", line 29, in <module>
decode = rs.decode(byteary)
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reedsolo.py", line 251, in decode
dec.extend(rs_correct_msg(chunk, self.nsym))
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reedsolo.py", line 213, in rs_correct_msg
raise ReedSolomonError("Could not locate error")
reedsolo.ReedSolomonError: Could not locate error
```

Comment: I found a similar question asking about added or dropped bits [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339083). Reed Solomon doesn't handle added or dropped bits. Trial and error can involve a lot of cases: 2 added bits would be combinations (145,2) = 10440 cases, 3 added bits (146,3) = 508080, 4 added bits (147,4) = 18671940, 5 added bits (148,5) = 552689424.

Comment: At some point, it might be simpler to check the number of bits received is correct and if not, retransmit.